# Problem while printing a pdf using base64 decoding in PHP

Tags: php, pdf, printing, pdf-generation

I'm trying to create a PHP program which prints a pdf which is encoded in Base64 to any kind of printer.

I already got the decoding done and the base64 pdf is being converted to a real PDF. However when I send the decoded Base64 to the printer it prints out the decoded string and not a PDF.

My code:

**Printer ip is disabled for development**

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$base64 = $_POST['fileBase64'];
$printer = $_POST['printer'];

printer('', 9100, $base64);

function printer($printerIp, $printerPort, $base64): void {
    $docname = md5(date("Y-m-d-H-i-s-Z")) . '.pdf';

    // Generate the pdf from the base64
    //Decode pdf content
    $pdf_decoded = base64_decode($base64);

    //Write data back to pdf file
    $pdf = fopen ($docname,'w');
    fwrite ($pdf, $pdf_decoded);

    //close output file
    fclose ($pdf);

    // echo file_get_contents($docname);

    try {
        $fp = pfsockopen($printerIp, $printerPort, $errno, $errstr);

        if ($fp === false) {
            echo 'Connection Failed! ' . $errno . ' ' . $errstr;
        } else {
            fputs($fp, file_get_contents($docname), filesize($docname));
            fclose($fp);

            echo "Successfully printed";

            // If done then delete pdf and clear text file
            exec("rm -rf '" . $docname . "'");
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }
}
```

Output of file_get_contents():
[image]

Comment: Can you try separating this into two parts: Successfully converting a base64 encoded blob into a valid file, and then successfully printing a file. For the former, you should be able to use a PDF validator. Once that's done, base64 encoding is out of the equation and we can just talk about printing a file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @ChrisHaas! I already removed the part where I used the txt file because that isn't necessary anymore. This already removes encoding from the process.

I'm also trying to do this with pure PHP so no extra downloads / libs (if possible).

Comment: No, 1.4 is absolutely a valid PDF version. Why are you echoing and writing? `echo file_get_contents($docname);` followed a little later by `fputs($fp, file_get_contents($docname), filesize($docname));`

Comment: I was trying to see what it sends to the printer via fputs.

Comment: Can you update your code above with exactly what you expect to work and isn't? Anything that is part of your debugging should be removed or commented out

Comment: The only thing that is not working is that the printer prints out the decoded Base64 and not the PDF itself

Comment: Okay, so I'm clicking a lot more now. You are calling `file_get_contents` and expecting it to be rendered somehow, but unless you have something like a RIP or other renderer (which you'd probably know if you did), you will only be printing the binary contents of the file. You need to have something render the file to the printer. This is the same as if you called `file_get_contents` on a JPEG, you wouldn't get an image, you'd get binary. Unfortunately, I have never printed from PHP, however my best guess is to shell this out to the system to render and print on your behalf.

Comment: What does the documentation say that the printer is expecting on its network port? Although PDF is based on PostScript, and PostScript is the native language of *some* printers, they're not the same thing, and many printers don't "speak" PostScript at all. I wouldn't expect a printer to automatically detect and interpret a PDF document without some additional commands to specify that that's what you were sending.

Comment: Hi @KJ im trying to create this program that it can print on any kind of printer. Not a specific printer. So I want it to work on Zebra printers but also normal inkjet printers. I see you added a bit of PJL as well but where would I be adding that?

Comment: Could you also attach a link with where I can find the right PJL code?

Comment: So this means it will be VERY hard with vanilla PHP? Is there a better way to programmatically send print jobs to any printer. Doesn't have to be in PHP.

Comment: Ok, I dont know how this answers my question in the comment on if it's possible. Do you know any tools or software which can do basically what I'm trying to achieve?